# Webpack config with multiple entries and a global site wide entry

Tags: javascript, requirejs, webpack

I'm moving from requirejs to webpack.
In my require js setup, I have a site-wide file `site.js` that does some global setup, and non-page-specific stuff, like ajax prefilters, some global ui component setup, etc.

Some pages have self contained js apps specifically for a given page, where I'd have `window.appPaths = ['some/path/to/app.js']` set in the template, and `site.js` would load up the app once the initial site wide stuff was done.

However, moving to webpack, it's reading my `require(window.appPaths)` and then it converts it to some regex and attempts to bundle every single js file in my src directory.

So basically, I'm wondering if there's a way for me to set this up to have multiple entry points, one being something like `site.js` and another being something like `somePageApp.js` wherein `site.js` is actually a dependency of the latter, but the latter doesn't *always* exist.

Sigh, hopefully that's clear, i'll elaborate where necessary.

---

edit: This is how it was set up in require.js setup, my output was:

html for an app page:

```
<script src="site.js">
<script>
  window.appPaths = ['someApp.js'];
</script>
```

site.js:

```
require([
  // deps for sitewide stuff
], function () {

  // doing global general stuff

  someTask(function () {
    if(window.appPaths) require(window.appPaths)
  })
})
```

someApp.js:

```
require([
  // app specific deps
], function () {
  // application code that doesn't run because not `require`d until the site.js tasks are done.
})
```

My "ideal" setup isn't necessarily the exact same, but I would want `someApp.js` to not load and/or run until site.js loaded. In my requirejs setup, site.js was also essentially the commons chunk but I don't think that's necessary here... just having trouble finding a parallel style of organization in webpack...

Comment: Could you show an example of what the scripts would look like _if it did work_?

Comment: @SeanLarkin updated with some more notes on my existing requirejs setup. Is that helpful? I guess _if it did work_ would be a similar organization to this?